# Child stdout set to "inherit" and "onData" listener

Tags: node.js, stream, stdio, child-process, spawn

In a nodejs application I need to spawn a child process with `stdio` set to "inherit" mode, so basically:

```
var child = spawn('some/command', [], {
  stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]
});
```

This is quite important because I am expecting the child process to write to it's stdout in raw mode and I want this "raw output" visible to my users as well. At the same time I want to parse a regular output from that process. Normally I would do:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function () {
  // ...
});
```

but in this case, there's no `child.stdout`. The second guess is to use `process.stdout`, but frankly

```
process.stdout.on('data', function () {
  // ...
});
```

is not working as well. I am wondering if there's any other way to capture that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a module like [`pty`](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js) that would allow you create a "fake tty" that you can read/write from/to.